# How to create a sidebar with latex?

Tags: latex, sidebar, journal

I need to make a journal, and I want to have a "recommended books" on the side of the page within the last page of the journal, but I couldn't find anything that would give me this result. I'm already using multicols package for the content and i cant see how a graphicx package would help me out.

I want to have a nice blue background with rounded corners too, help is welcome ^^.

Comment: Try using the [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/) package for placing the box and the [fancybox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox/) package for formatting the box. From [Rob Hyndman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144157/rob-hyndman)

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using multicol, just make it another column and draw a box around it with the usual techniques.  Maybe not the fanciest solution, but it seems like it should work.  Use `\newcolumn` in the multicol environment to put the sidebar in its own column.  For your fancy boxes, try [the `fancybox` package.](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fancybox/)  With it, you can draw boxes with rounded corners.

On the other hand, [this guy](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/07/wrapping-text-in-rounded-corners-colorbox-in-latex-with-tikz-and-pgf/) gets super fancy and uses the `TikZ` package to get colors and all sorts of stuff.